# No margin HTML header

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and CSS. I am trying to create a header with no margins on the edges. How would I do this? My code is below. I haven't been able to find a straight answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE>


<html>
<link type="css/text" href="Gifter.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>
    </title>



<head>
</head>

    <body>
        <div>EXAMPLE</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

And my CSS.

```
div{
border:solid black 1px;
}
```

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but your doctype statement is non-standard. You may run into some quirks mode problems. Try <!doctype html> instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0
}
```

This will remove margin from your page body, effectively drawing DIV from edge to edge

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cznkS/

Answer (score 2):

Try below `CSS`

```
body{
    margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give Padding and margin of the  to 0.

```
body
{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

This is because.. The body specifies some margin and padding by default to align their internal elements.

Your [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/T4t39/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
*{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }
body{ 
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   }
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html,body{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```